# find the value of p to get converges (Improper Integrals)

Tags: calculus

find for which values of p the integral converges

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\text{d}x}{x^p}\text{}$$

I just use the definition of the improper integrals and to separate into two parts.

one is from 0~1 and one is from 1~inf , after that , I cant find any real number which is suitable for

this question in order to take that two parts both Converges..

how could I do that?

btw.
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{\text{d}x}{x^p}\text{}$$ p>1---Converges
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\text{d}x}{x^p}\text{}$$ p<1---Converges

Comment: I would just use upper and lower integrals (sometimes called upper and lower Darboux sums) to compare to the p-series

Comment: Hence the correct answer: for none.

Comment: I have asked my teacher. he said it has answer..

Comment: 1) What are the "problematic" (singular) points for this integral?

2) How can we express the integral using limits an proper integrals?

3) Does the integral converge for p=1?

4) If p != 1, what is the primitve function of the integrand?

5) Calculate the integral using (2) and (4), and then see for which values
of p the integral converges.

this is my teachers hits

Comment: @haoyigu: Are you sure you copy "the integral" correctly? If it comes from your notes/book, can you give a screen shot?

Comment: "and then see for which values of p the integral converges." such question does not guarantee that such $p$ exists.

Comment: am sure this one is correct. and I can give u another example about that.

Answer (score 1):

You want a real number $p$ such that both
$$
\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^p}\,dx\quad\textrm{and}\quad \int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x^p}\,dx\tag{0}
$$
are convergent. As you have observed, such $p$ does not exist.

---

Notes.
On $(0,\infty)$,
$$
\int \frac{1}{x^p} dx = \frac{1}{1-p}x^{1-p}+C,\quad p\ne 1\tag{1}
$$
$$
\int \frac1x dx = \ln x+C\quad \tag{2}
$$

So you see when $p=1$, neither integral in $(0)$ converges.

If $p<1$, then $1-p>0$, $\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x^p}\,dx$ diverges.

If $p>1$, then $1-p<0$, $\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^p}\,dx$ diverges.